# Elasticsearch counts of all indices

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to get counts of all indices. I am using `_all` in the URL. The following code works but its not returning data for all indices.

```
GET /_all/_search?search_type=count&q=_type:invoice
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      }
    }
}
```

}

Most of the indices are skipped in the output. Is there any limit on indices or there is something wrong in my code?

Comment: Do you have a type called invoice in all your indexes?

Comment: Yes, i have type invoice for all

Comment: Ok, then what should be there for _index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default, the limit of the returned results is 10: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html.

> To start with, this example groups all the accounts by state, and then returns the top 10 (default) states sorted by count descending (also default)

The same applies for `terms` aggregation: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size

In your case, you need something like this:

```
GET /_all/_search?search_type=count&q=_type:invoice
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```